# I'm having difficulty understanding the price of magic arms and armor special abilities

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items

Can anyone help clear up the prices of magic arms and armor? I am looking at some magic special abilities and they have entries that say things like *Price +1 bonus*, for example, the magic weapon special ability [*flaming*](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsAW.html#flaming).

I know that before such an item can have a magic armor or weapon special ability, the item must first have a +1 enhancement bonus. A +1 enhancement bonus is, on its own, 2,000 gp. Does the magic weapon special ability *flaming* add a *different* +1 to that 2,000 gp price for a total price of 4,000 gp? Or is the total +2 enhancement bonus *combined* so that the weapon's price is 8,000g? (This doesn't include the separate prices for the item and its masterwork component, of course.)

Comment: I feel like I've answered this question, more or less, [before](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/20172/4563)... Voting to close as a duplicate.

Comment: @KRyan I think the answer is about the same but the question's point of difficulty is different enough to fall under [loving the non-exact duplicate](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When special abilities modify the enhancement bonus, you use the total enhancement bonus to determine cost. This applies to weapons, armor and shields.

> Special abilities count as additional bonuses for determining the market value of the item, but do not modify attack or damage bonuses (except where specifically noted). A single weapon cannot have a modified bonus (enhancement bonus plus special ability bonus equivalents) higher than +10.

Your example of a +1 Flaming weapon has a +2 enhancement bonus and thus costs 8000g + base item and masterworking.

Some qualities from outside of the SRD have direct cost modifiers like +300gp. These just add on to the price instead of changing the enhancement bonus.

Comment: I believe there is a caveat of an additional cost for multiple unrelated enchants. For instance a Keen Flaming shortsword?

Comment: You'll have to give a citation for that. Sounds like a houserule to me.

Comment: @Ben-Jamin There is no such additional cost when stacking weapon or armor enhancements. You may be thinking of the cost-addition rules for creating combined wondrous items, from the Magic Item Compendium.

Comment: @Ben-Jamin You might also be thinking of the extra 2,000 gp that has to be paid when enchanting a cold iron weapon, which by RAW was paid every single time you added another enchantment. I think every GM I've ever met houseruled that it only had to be paid the first time, though.

Comment: I think @Ernir hit what I was talking about..my last DM must have combined it into weapos with a houserule which explains why I could never find the reference