# How many different magical damage qualities can a single weapon have & how it relates to price?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, weapons, damage-types

For this question I'm talking about things like flaming/ flaming burst or icy burst/ frost brand, shocking burst, brilliant energy, thundering, and so on.

I'm excluding properties that deal with alignment issues, harm a specific type of creature, dance/ defend, increases distance, returns it to you if thrown, etc.

Also, I'm wanting to know how these interact with the item's price (for instance some will say +3 price, so does that mean that it counts as a +3 weapon, even if it doesn't state it does?)

RAW is good, but tested houserules work just as well.

Comment: Also related: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/20172/confusion-about-magic-weapon-pricing?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

### As many as can fit within the +10 enhancement maximum

From the section on [Magic Weapons](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicWeapons.htm):

> In addition to an enhancement bonus, weapons may have special abilities. Special abilities count as additional bonuses for determining the market value of the item, but do not modify attack or damage bonuses (except where specifically noted). *A single weapon cannot have a modified bonus (enhancement bonus plus special ability bonus equivalents) higher than +10. A weapon with a special ability must have at least a +1 enhancement bonus.*

Since a weapon must have at least +1 enhancement before adding special abilities, that leaves +9 worth to fill.

There is nothing saying that you can't combine "opposite" effects (though the alignment effects *strongly imply* it - I don't think a weapon could count as *both* lawful *and* chaotic at once).

*But*, some enhancements are command-activated, so depending on your interpretation, *maybe* can't be active at the same time:

> **Upon command**, a flaming weapon is sheathed in fire. The fire does not harm the wielder. The effect remains **until another command is given**.

(depends whether you read "another command" as "the 'off' command for this effect", or "*any other command* related to this weapon")

---

So, if you want a numerical "How many?", **the answer is 9.**

(eg, a *+1 flaming, frost, shock, thundering, keen, ghost touch, defending, mighty cleaving, spell storing*... weapon)

---

In regards to price, look again at my first quote:

> Special abilities count as additional bonuses for determining the market value of the item

This means that you total up all of the weapon's effective bonuses, then look up the cost for that bonus on the cost table. Eg, your maxed-out, total effective +10 bonus weapon will cost 200,000 GP for the magic, *plus* the cost of the weapon itself (which *must* be Masterwork, and *can* be made from special materials such as Adamantine). This is "base cost", or market value. The cost for the magic part is halved if you are crafting it yourself.

Comment: Why do you think two command-activated properties can't be active at once? Seems obvious to me that the intent of "until another command is given" is: "There is a specific second command word to turn it off" and not "_any_ other word you say will turn it off".

Comment: @topquark I think it's a little vague. I've changed my definite "can't" to a "maybe can't" - it doesn't change the rest of my answer.

Comment: I'm on mobile right now, but we have a question about this that you could reference

Comment: The question becomes on "opposites" do they cancel each other out (and thus provide no benefit) if activated at the same time

Comment: Perhaps this gets pedantic, but the "+1" would count as a magic damage effect on its own for a flat 1 damage. You can also argue that certain of the special materials count as "different magical damage qualities". That may be getting away from the spirit of the question, but I think it's worth a side note. Anyway, that would bring the numeric up to 10 or 11.

Comment: Note on your last paragraph regarding crafting, yes crafting costs are "only" half, but the 200,000 max is set on the "market value" not how much you can spend on it.

Comment: @Ben-Jamin I didn't say that 200,000 GP is the max. I said +10 equivalent is the max, *which would cost* 200,000 GP market value.