# Cost of adding magic weapon abilities

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, weapons, pricing

So I'm starting in a campaign at 6th level, and I used some of my starting money to buy a +1 adamantine nodachi for around 4,000gp (we had a party member with craft magic arms and armor) I want to put Keen on it, that would put the base price in enchantments up to 8,000, (4,000 with craft magic arms and armor) would the price from +1 carry over to the new base price? And would adding Keen cost 3,000gp, 4,000gp, 7,000gp, or 8,000?

Comment: Sorry, misread your question - apologies the first answer was off topic.

Comment: [Related](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/20172/confusion-about-magic-weapon-pricing?rq=1), though I think a general answer about how masterwork weapons, weapon pricing, enhancement, special materials and crafting must exist on this site, I am unable to find and link that.

Comment: I corrected your title; while 'enchantment' is a colloquial term used about magically improving equipment, it has a different use in Pathfinder (one of the spellcasting 'schools' relating to charming/compulsion/etc ie 'they were enchanting to talk to') and could (however unlikely) cause confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would subtract the cost of the +1 weapon from the cost of a +2 weapon, and pay the remainder, in this case, a total of 6,000 GP.

A +1 Adamantine nodachi would cost an additional +5,000 GP over the weapon cost, and to add Keen to it would then cost an additional 6,000 GP.

A +1 weapon by itself would add 2,000 GP to the base cost, and a +2 weapon would cost an additional 8,000 over the base price of the weapon.

8000 - 2000 = 6000 GP.

The adamantine special material does not impact the magic weapon pricing for enhancements.

http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/

http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/special-materials/

Comment: Understood, one more thing though. How, if at all, does this interact with craft magic arms and armor? Is anything affected if the +1 was added with craft magic arms and armor and Keen wasn't?

Comment: Can you describe such a case when Keen would be added to the weapon without using Craft Magic Arms and Armor? Do you mean like through a temporary effect, instead of making it a permanent enhancement?

Comment: I think it would be a case of having an npc do it, and paying full price for the service.

Comment: Oh, refer to these two statement in the Craft Magic Arms and Armor feats - "Enhancing a weapon, suit of armor, or shield takes 1 day for each 1,000 gp in the price of its magical features. To enhance a weapon, suit of armor, or shield, you must use up raw materials *costing half of this total price*." So, Craft Magic Arms and armor would reduce the *magical* portions of the cost of the weapon by half. However, Craft Magic Arms and Armor would not reduce the cost of the adamantine special material of the weapon. If you plan on crafting that item, you'd need to refer to the Crafting Rules.

Comment: You should add in your answer that the total cost will actually be 3000gp if his buddy takes 6 days to craft it.